# How practical is the sandcrawler as a vehicle?

Tags: science-based, vehicles

A sandcrawler is is a tracked vehicle about 40 meters long, 20 meters tall, and 15 meters wide. It has a thick outer hull for protection from the elements. It has eight sets of tracks, four abreast forward and aft for support. It is designed to operate in hot and sandy desert environments. In the Star Wars universe, this [vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandcrawler) is the Jawas' primary means of transport around Tatooine.

From an engineering perspective, how practical would such a vehicle be?

I imagine that the high center of mass would pose stability issues, especially over uneven terrain, and the eight sets of tracks would severely limit speed.

Comment: "Practical"? For what? "especially over uneven terrain" - but it is never shown to travel over such terrain. "severely limit speed" - I never seen or heard it to need high speed. So - practical for what?

Comment: Also, site for questions on already built worlds in published works is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please describe the concept of a Sandcrawler for those that are not familiar with this vehicle. Especially with a focus on what you think the important parts are for this question. Maybe you could include a small picture or sketch to illustrate your ideas.

Comment: @Mołot My guess is that Sci-Fi SE wouldn't be interested in technical questions about *Star Wars* vehicles & technology. It's likely they would migrate to WB SE>

Comment: @a4android they already have a handful of open and decently received questions about technical aspects of Star Wars vehicles: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=star-wars+vehicles - that's a fact, not a guess. Anyway, OP here is not building any world, so asking on worlbbuilding is wrong choice, even if there is no better one on Stack Exchange.

Comment: A Sandcrawler is about as practical as an Imperial Walker is.  In other words, idiotic. :-)

Comment: @StephenG Nope. It fullfills it's designated role very well. It's just that it's true role is to amaze and look & feel strange, out of this world.

Comment: @a4android the scifi exchange takes tech questions for star-wars vehicles, [I even posted one myself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149548/how-does-the-b-wings-cockpit-maintain-correct-orientation-in-space)

Comment: I feel like people are being a little too un-helpful with this question. I edited the question with a quick description. Just because a vehicle is _like_ something from an already created universe, doesn't mean we can't discuss it here. If you are looking to incorporate a sandcrawler into your own world, that would be on topic, regardless if someone had though up the idea first. This question should not be closed.

Comment: @kingledion the issue is still asking about 'how practical' the vehicle would be. Practicability cannot really be judged unless you have a (list of) role(s) it need to fulfill.

Comment: @Mołot *Fiction* alright, but the very last word that comes to mind when thinking about the Star Wars sandcrawler is *science*. ;-)

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Thanks for the factual correction. I did make it plain I was guessing. My concern was sending the OP somewhere the question might not be acceptable. So I'm glad to know it would be.

Comment: @kingledion Agreed. The question is about the practicality of this type of vehicle. Anyone could post the same question describing the vehicle without any *Star Wars* references and it would be acceptable as worldbuilding.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T The sandcrawler is a form of transport. Therefore, what is its practicality as transport. What other roles does it need to fulfill?

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what you want to do with it, it might be a good or a bad design. The number you give do not completely fit with the picture but don't sound so bad.

So not giving it any from gives the following shape with a center of mass about 7.5 m above the ground.

[image: Schematic of the sandcrawler]

So do you have any change of tipping over in rough terrain? If you go nose first everything is probably ok, sideways gives more danger but not as much as you would suspect. The tipping point is if the Center of Mass (CoM) lays outside the base, this only happens after a tilt of 40 degrees as can be seen in the picture.

[image: Tipping of the sandcrawler]

So what is the ground pressure it has. To calculate this you need the weight of the crawler and the area of the tracks. For the area of the track I took half the area of the bottom. For the weight I took 140 time the weight of the [Maus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzer_VIII_Maus) as this is the biggest tank build and this is roughly how many times the Maus fits in the crawler. I think I am highly over estimating the weight since the armoured plating only has to be on the outside so I took half the weight, but you can use any number you want.

So the ground pressure exerted by the crawler becomes:

[image: Formula]

Ok so this is a bit heavy but it is somewhere between a montouain bike and a road racing bike, [see this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure), wikipedia of course.

If the weight reduced (which I think is logical) and add slightly more track surface the contraption seems feasible. Whether it is usable depends on the application.

One note on speed, since it is such a huge mass with relative high CoM you need to take care of the inertia of the crawler. Any slightly tight cornering at higher speed will cause it to tip over.

Comment: If most of the crawler's weight (Engines and track assembly, perhaps) is towards the bottom of the vehicle then the COM can be much, much lower. There are a few kids toys that abuse this effect to make [seemingly impossible objects](https://www.amazon.com/Toysmith-4035-Balancing-Eagle-7-Inch/dp/B004R6VB2E).

Comment: @Joe, Good comment, I indeed used a homogeneous mass distribution due to lack of data. The OP can split the vehicle in different sections with different masses and add the weighted CoM of each component to get the actual center of mass of the entire body to get a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 9):

The Sandcrawler is hilariously badly designed for any kind of realistic use. The fact that it is so thin from one direction means that the incredible weight of the thing would cause it to sink into the sand.

We already had problems with sinking into mud and sand during WW2 with heavy tanks like the Tiger and the KV. And at least those had wide bottoms to spread out the weight which meant it didn't sink into the ground *as easily*. The Sandcrawler is 10 times the size with a terrible weight distribution. It would really only be usable on a planet with a hard rock surface. It would sink into any ground that was even remotely soft.

And the biggest problem with the treads isn't that they'd be slow. Modern tanks can go quite fast with an M1 Abrams having a top speed of 60mph (96.5 km/h). The problem with the sand crawler's is that the treads are so close together turning would be a slow tedious nightmare.

If used in warfare it would be a massive target as well and any attempt to armor it would only exacerbate the aforementioned issues.

Comment: /The problem with the sand crawler's is that the treads are so close together turning would be a slow tedious nightmare/ - excellent

Comment: Sandcrawlers aren't designed for warfare to begin with (they're scavenger vehicles), so that point and the slowness don't really matter.

Comment: Would allowing the treads (Maybe pairs?) to pivot help with the turning? Or would that make the whole thing tip over like just about anything else?

Comment: Although, to be fair, the design realistically doesn't have to worry about tipping over, since it's just going to sink into the ground anyway.

Comment: @Andon Honestly, the whole thing is so top heavy any shift from 90 degrees in either direction might tip it over.

Comment: In canon, the treads do appear to be mounted on bogies which can individually pivot. It still wouldn't turn very quickly, even with bogies + some sort of tank-type transmission.